# How to get the value of mysql.user password

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, web

**When I log in I am using the mysql.user but I can't log on if the user has a password. If i logged on using any user a with password the page can't logged on to the other php.**

The user inputted on the log in will be use on the connection for the database.

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>


 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Log in</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure.css">

 <?php include('connection.php'); ?>

 </head>

 <body>
 <form class="box login" method="post">
    <fieldset class="boxBody">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="Username" required  name="username" id="username">
      <label><label class="rLink" tabindex="5">Optional</label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" >
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
      <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Login" tabindex="4" name="sent">
    </footer>
</form>

 <?php

  if (isset($_POST['sent'])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $message="";

    // Create connection
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT user FROM mysql.user where user='$username' and password='$password'");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                    
      $_SESSION["uname"] = "$username";
      $_SESSION["pass"] = "$password";
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(<?php echo "Success!";?>)</script>';
      header("location: main.php");
  } else {
        $message = "Successfuly entered! hi! $username";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(<?php echo "$message";?>)</script>'; 
    }
}           

 // Check connection
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you can set it, or you can login, you can't get the non-hashed value from a hashed. You can call `SET PASSWORD FOR 'jeffrey'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password'); `

Comment: I suppose that you want to "alert" when you found an user or if you do not:
`
 if ($result->num_rows > 0){                 
            $_SESSION["uname"] = "$username";
            $_SESSION["pass"] = "$password";
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("")</script>';
                header("location: main.php");
                } else {
                    $message = "Successfuly entered! hi! $username";
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$message.'")</script>';}
                }           
`
You forgot quotes for "alert" parameters.

Comment: @BenoitNgô the password on my query for select does not  function,

Answer (score 1):

You'd better check for database errors that might happen here

```
$conn->query("SELECT user FROM mysql.user where user='$username' and password='$password'");
```

Check if the query executes first.
Its also better to use this one

```
"SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user= ?"
```

After checking row count. You can hash current password with user's salt then check if they are equal.

For more security use prepared statements.And check if `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` are set too (even if your input fields are "required")

And for echoing your errors you can have a paragraph with error id

```
<p id="error"></p>
```

And echo this one

```
    '<script>
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "'.$error.'"
</script>'
```

My first answer sorry for bad English.